# TinyMCE insert raw html into active editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Using WindowManager for TinyMCE I open a window and it writes back raw HTML. But its truncating my links for my images. Whats weird is that it does NOT do it to the anchor tag. Just the image tag.

I have this bit of code

```
html = '<a title="'+ $('#title').val() +'" href="'+ $('#url').val() +'"><img src="'+ $('#imgURL').val() +'" /></a>';

    var parentEditor = parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    parentEditor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, html);
    parentEditor.windowManager.close();
```

It DOES insert the html into the active Editor. When I log **html** to the console I get

```
<a title="Click Action" href="yahoo.com"><img src="http://marketingedu.mychm.co/images/buttons/c2a-button4.png" /></a>
```

However when I view the Source Code in the tinyMCE editor, it changed the images SRC attribute to

```
../../images/buttons/c2a-button4.png
```

Here is my entire javascript init for the TinyMCE editor

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".editor",
        setup: function(ed) {
            ed.on('change', function(e) {
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();

                $('form').trigger('checkform.areYouSure');
            });
            ed.on('init', function(e) {
                autoresize_max_height: 500
            });
            ed.addButton('defaultbtn', {
                title: 'Insert Button',
                icon: 'fa fa-plus-square',
                onclick: function() {
                    // Open window
                    ed.windowManager.open({
                        title: 'Button Selector',
                        url: "<?=$this->url('/webinar/custombuttons') ?>",
                        width: 800,
                        height: 600
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link responsivefilemanager lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "save table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor colorpicker responsivefilemanager autoresize"
        ],
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | outdent indent | table | link responsivefilemanager defaultbtn",
        image_advtab: true ,

        external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change this:

```
var parentEditor = parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
parentEditor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, html);
```

To This:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(html, {format: 'raw'});
```

Here is a reference [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#setcontent) on how to set content on tinymce in various of ways.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is working with html, but what if I wanna add some js code like so `<script>alert("loaded");</script>`

Comment: @Jie you'll need to [allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850969/2518317) them

Comment: This post saved the day. It solved it for me. Thanks. Up rated